# How to call Actions.xxx in functions binded to onPress event in 'react-native-router-flux'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flux

I'm using RN0.24 and flux3.26. RN version may be out-dated but the `Actions.xxx` works fine when I'm using `onPress={Actions.xxx}`
However once I put it into functions like `onPress={this.function}` and in function i do 
`function(event){ Actions.xxx; }` then it's not working
can anyone help with this?

Comment: I don't know RN, but native JavaScript events binds an `element` on which the event is fired as context `this` into callbacks, if you attach callback `Actions.xxx` as an event listener, it binds `this` into it, but if you attach `function(event) { Actions.xxx }` then it binds `this` into the anonymous function and your `Action.xxx` has `this` referencing to `Action`, you can try rebind `this` like **`function(event){ Action.xxx.bind(this) }`**, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Sorry, the code is wrong, use either `function(event){ Action.xxx.bind(this)() }` or `function(event){ Action.xxx.call(this) }`

Comment: @Vaclav just solved it lol，call Actions.xxx() works, thx anyway！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `this` issue, I think you can try:

```
render() {
    const login = () => { Action.login() }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome} onPress={ login }>
          Go to Login
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this can he helpful.

Comment: lol I have figured it out myself, but this seems to be similar to my solution, so I'll just accept as correct.