# react-native-router-flux Calling Actions from function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

This is my currently working login page. Everything works fine

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AlertIOS , StyleSheet , View , Text} from 'react-native';
import Button from 'react-native-button';
import {Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <View>
               <Text>Hello world this is login page</Text>
               <Button onPress={Actions.login2}>Click </Button>
           </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

However, I want to call function first for check the username and password.If it's correct I want to go to next screen. How can i achieve this. Like this code below. My real problem is I couldn't figure out calling `Actions.ROUTE_NAME` method outside of the render method.

```
//This is not working
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AlertIOS , StyleSheet , View , Text} from 'react-native';
import Button from 'react-native-button';
import {Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

class Login extends Component {
controlMethod(){
if(true){Actions.login2}
}
    render() {
        return (
           <View>
               <Text>Hello world this is login page</Text>
               <Button onPress={this.controlMethod}>Click </Button>
           </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: this might answer you question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346979/how-to-call-actions-xxx-in-functions-binded-to-onpress-event-in-react-native-ro

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try this one :

```
controlMethod(){
  if(true){ Actions.login2() }
}
```

let's try using `()`

hope it can solve you're problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Rizal is right, in your second example, you passed in `controlMethod` function to the `onPress` prop, when you click on `<Button>` component, the `controlMethod` will get executed, but in your second example the `controlMethod` will not actually execute the `Actions.login2` function but instead it will return the [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions), so to make it work, you want to actually invoke the `Actions.login2` which is why you need another pair of parenthesis after the `Actions.login2` just like Rizal's example shows.

Also, make sure you bind your `controlMethod` in your constructor or you can make it a static method instead.